# Cycle through list items: CSS or JS?

Tags: javascript, css

I have the following bar, it's a `<ul>` where some list items aren't being shown. When the arrows are clicked, I need the elements to be moved left or right by accondingly hiding or showing the leftmost/rightmost ones.

[image: ...]

### My HTML

```html
<div id="linkbar">
    <a href="#linkbar" onclick="moveleft();"><img src="./img/arrowleft.png"></a>
    <div id="linkbarinternal">
        <ul id="linkbaritems">
            <li><a><img src="./img/banner01.jpg"></a></li>
            <li><a><img src="./img/banner02.jpg"></a></li>
            <li><a><img src="./img/banner03.jpg"></a></li>
            <li><a><img src="./img/banner04.jpg"></a></li>
            <li><a><img src="./img/banner05.jpg"></a></li>
            <li><a><img src="./img/banner06.jpg"></a></li>
            <li><a><img src="./img/banner07.jpg"></a></li>
            <li><a><img src="./img/banner08.jpg"></a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <a href="#linkbar" onclick="moveright();"><img src="./img/arrowright.png"></a>
</div>
```

### What I've tried

```
var linkbarcounter = 0;

function moveleft() {
    document.getElementById("linkbaritems").children[linkbarcounter++].style.display="none";
}

function moveright() {
    document.getElementById("linkbaritems").children[--linkbarcounter].style.display="inline";
}
```

Comment: @PhilippeBoissonneault The problem is I don't know JS enough to even know where to start. I don't even know if it using JavaScript is the right approach, I'm guessing it is.  Maybe I'm wrong?

Comment: Updated question with what I've tried so far

Answer (score 0):

```
var bar = document.getElementById("linkbar");
for(var i=0;i<bar.children.length; i++)
    // Do whatever per item.
    console.log(i ,bar.children[i]);
```